# Error with two byte UTF-8 character in UPDATE statement for MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, groovy, utf-8

An update-statement seems to work only with one or three byte long UTF-8 characters.

My test code

```
def sql = sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://.../...?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8',
            '...', '...', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
String value = 'β'
sql.execute('UPDATE Kldb_SynonymVersion SET synonyms=? WHERE id=11940', [value])
```

fails with

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'synonyms' at row 1
```

in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket.

It works with value="a" or value = '€'.

I am using

java 1.6.0_20
mysql 5.0.26
mysql-connector 5.1.13

The character-set of the table is set to utf8.

I know that I can disable the truncation, but than I only avoid the exception and get an invalid character ('?') in the database.

Comment: I know nothing about Java, but doesn't it use UTF-16 by default? Wouldn't you have to convert the `ß` into an UTF-8 character first?

Comment: Whats a type of column? CHAR(1) or CHAR(2)? make it longer.

Comment: The type of the column is TEXT

Comment: @Pekka: maybe, but why does it work with '@' - a 3 byte UTF-8 character?

Comment: @Th. `@` is most definitely a 1-byte character in UTF-8. It's part of the basic ASCII character set.

Comment: The '€' ist stored in the database as the three byte sequence E2 82 AC

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that column encoding of MySQL column is UTF-8.

MySQL driver is able to write unicode characters to ASCII columns, and even read them correctly, so the problem can be unnotified for long time.